# System.Data.DataRow.ObjectID is not accessible in this context because it is 'friend'

Tags: debugging, compiler-errors, vb.net-2010, datarow

I'm having trouble debugging an error which appears in my live test environment but not my localhost environment, I've been sending values to the page to view behaviour a specific points in page load. This has been working well until now, I'm trying to draw out the ObjectID of a DataRow and get the message:

*System.Data.DataRow.ObjectID is not accessible in this context because it is 'friend'*

This is for

> dr.ObjectID

which I call within the following For loop

> For Each dr As DataRow In
>   SessionProxy.PolicyData.dsCustomer.CUSTOMER_ADDON.Rows

I've search around for ideas on what I could do to resolve this but nothing which helps. I found help around System.Data.Function, but I can't get inside the class to temporarily change the Friend status or make other changes as its 3rd party software, which just so happens to be completely undocumented.

Does anyone have any tricks I can use to identify this data, when I use the debugger to look at the data I can pick out dr.ObjectID but I am unable to compile it to view in a live environment.

Please let me know if I need to provide more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be with the underlying table which had been populated with null data in some required fields. There had been issues with combining logical `And` and `Or` SQL code which using brackets to separate out the query correctly resolved, thus correcting the `DataView` at source ensured no null data was coming through.

The good news here is that the issues experienced encourage more robust defensive programming on this platform I inherited a while back to ensure these issues are picked up before crashing a website.